# Get current timestamp VHDL

Tags: timestamp, automated-tests, vhdl

In order to create a random seed, I would like to **get the system timestamp** in my VHDL testbench.

How can I do that?

By the way, I'm using the RandomPkg from the [OSVVM library](http://osvvm.org/downloads)

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a generic VHDL approach, you can pass the system time as generic to the test bench entity.  If the test bench looks like:

```
entity seed_tb is
  generic(SEED : natural := 0);
end entity;

architecture sim of seed_tb is
begin
  assert FALSE report "SEED = " & integer'image(SEED) severity NOTE;
end architecture;
```

Then on Linux with the ModelSim simulator, the command lines for compile and run can be:

```
> vlib work
> vcom seed_tb.vhd
> vsim seed_tb -c -gSEED=`date +%s` -do "run; exit"
```

The `date +%s` give seconds since 1970-01-01, which will fit in the VHDL natural type (even for another 25 years :-).

The approach has the advantage that it is easy to rerun the simulation with the same seed from the command line, in case debugging is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

With a VHDL tool suite that supports foreign objects (architectures, sub programs) you could have a foreign subprogram returning the system time from a system call.

You could place a seed value in a file and read it.  A shell script wrapper that does so and invokes your simulator comes to mind.

A procfs function could provide access to system time as a file read.

You might gather the notion of system time isn't of general important in VHDL.